# Ajax GET sends null data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get data based on what a user has selected in a drop down menu. I'm able to nab the selected value, but when I pass it to the controller in MVC 5, the data is null. Any ideas?

**jQuery**

```
LoadData($("#Dropdown").val());
function LoadData(selectedID) {
    console.log(selectedID); //displays the right ID that was selected
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',
        type: "GET", 
        dataType: "json", 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { selectedID: selectedID}, 
        success: function (data) {...} 
        ...
    });
};
```

**C#**

```
public ActionResult GetData(string selectedID) 
{
    // Get data here
    return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior. AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `[HttpGet]` above the action definition?

Comment: @JoshMein yeah, I've done that. Nothing changed unfortunately...

Comment: which data is null? selectedID in MVC method or data in jquery success callback?

Comment: what about if you try: `data: { 'selectedID': selectedID}`

Comment: @MehmetCanKamar selectedID is null in the MVC method. That console.log() line in the jQuery is outputting the right/non-null value.

Comment: @M12Bennett selectedID is still null, unfortunately...

Comment: Not 100% sure about this.. but what if that action is a POST action and not a GET?

Comment: In your route config, what is the default route? I think it uses that.. and in which case you would need to change `selectedID` in your actionresult method to `id`

Comment: Remove the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` option (you are not stringifying the data, and a GET has no body in any case - you need to use the default `contentType` which is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`)

Comment: Check whether your parameter name in ajax is same as in controller function. This is silly but it happens sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I have the following workaround for this since I don't know why it's passing a null value to the MVC method, when that console.log() value is displaying a non-null value. It works. It's not pretty, but it works.

I replaced the URL in the Ajax call with:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetData")?selectedID=' + selectedID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing a mistkake in the return of your controller, can you try to return the value like this instead:

```
return Json(new { results = results }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then in your jquery success you can access the data like this :

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.results)
}
```